# Webscrape skipping invalid input

Tags: excel, html, vba

I'm trying to create a web scraper and I really need help!

Currently, this program will run in a way such that the main input "Module Code" will be taken from Column A Row 2 onward all the way till it ends.
The outputs (Module Title, Description, Prereq, and Preclusion) will be scraped from the website.

However, I have trouble trying to make the program skip a row if the input given does not provide any output.

Currently, if `Cells(15, 1)` is an invalid input, it will continue with `Cells(16, 1)` and place the outputs for `Cells(16, 2 to 5)` to `Cells(15, 2 to 5)`. Thus, if there is an error in the input, I will have a missing row at the end.

However, what I wish to achieve is if `Cells(15, 1)` is an invalid input, it will leave `Cells(15, 2 to 5)` empty and continue on with `Cell(16, 1)` as the input and place the output to `Cells(16, 2 to 5)` instead of the previous row.

Will be great if anyone can guide me with this! I am still trying to learn VBA as a newbie.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim module_title As String
Dim module_description As String
Dim module_prereq As String
Dim module_preclusion As String
Dim module_code As String

For i = 2 To 200
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Exit For
    ModuleCode.Text = Cells(i, 1)
    module_code = ModuleCode.Text

    Call GotoModules(module_code, module_title, module_description, module_prereq, module_preclusion)

    ModuleTitle.Text = module_title
    ModuleDescription.Text = module_description
    ModulePrereq.Text = module_prereq
    ModulePreclude.Text = module_preclusion
    output_row = 1
    DoEvents
    output_row = output_row + 1
    Sheets("Output").Range("B" & output_row) = module_title
    Sheets("Output").Range("C" & output_row) = module_description
    Sheets("Output").Range("D" & output_row) = module_prereq
    Sheets("Output").Range("E" & output_row) = module_preclusion
Next i

End Sub
```

The function is as shown:

```
Function GotoModules(ModuleCode As String, module_title As String, module_description As String, module_prereq As String, module_preclusion As String)

'module_code = ""
module_title = ""
module_description = ""
module_prereq = ""
module_preclusion = ""

If ModuleCode = "" Then Exit Function

the_start:

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600
'objIE.AddressBar = 0
'objIE.StatusBar = 0
'objIE.Toolbar = 0
objIE.Visible = True 'To see window navigation

objIE.Navigate ("https://myaces.nus.edu.sg/cors/jsp/report/ModuleDetailedInfo.jsp?acad_y=2017/2018&sem_c=2&mod_c=" & ModuleCode)

Do
DoEvents
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = Nothing
        GoTo the_start:
    End If
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

the_HTML_ToParse = objIE.Document.Body.InnerHTML
'UserForm1.TextBox6.Text = the_HTML_ToParse
'Exit Function


'Remove before Module Information
If InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Module Information") > 0 Then

'Parses up to the point where "Module Information" string is
the_HTML_ToParse = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Module Information"), Len(the_HTML_ToParse)) 'Parses from Module Information onwards
HTML_Parse_Prereq = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Pre-requisite"), Len(the_HTML_ToParse))
HTML_Parse_Preclusion = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Preclusion"), Len(the_HTML_ToParse))

'Module Title Parse
the_HTML_ToParse = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "<TD colSpan=2>") + 14, Len(the_HTML_ToParse))
the_module_title = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, 1, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "</TD></TR>") - 1)

'Module Description Parse
the_HTML_ToParse = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "<TD vAlign=top colSpan=2>") + 25, Len(the_HTML_ToParse))
the_module_description = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, 1, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "</TD></TR>") - 1)

'Module Prerequisite Parse
HTML_Parse_Prereq = Mid(HTML_Parse_Prereq, InStr(HTML_Parse_Prereq, "<TD colSpan=2>") + 14, Len(HTML_Parse_Prereq))
the_module_prereq = Mid(HTML_Parse_Prereq, 1, InStr(HTML_Parse_Prereq, "</TD></TR>") - 1)

'Module Preclusion Parse
HTML_Parse_Preclusion = Mid(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, InStr(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, "<TD colSpan=2>") + 14, Len(HTML_Parse_Preclusion))
the_module_preclusion = Mid(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, 1, InStr(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, "</TD></TR>") - 1)



module_title = the_module_title
module_description = the_module_description
module_prereq = the_module_prereq
module_preclusion = the_module_preclusion


End If


objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing
'GotoModules = "Page has loaded"

End Function


Function GetCountByTagName(objIE As Object, what_tag_name As String)
GetCountByTagName = 0

the_count = -1
On Error Resume Next

Do
DoEvents
the_count = the_count + 1
Set the_element = objIE.Document.getElementsbyTagName(what_tag_name).Item(the_count)
a = the_element.Name 'This will cause an Err.Number once there are no more elements in the tag name
If Err.Number = 0 Then GetCountByTagName = the_count + 1
Loop Until Err.Number <> 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a re-write

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click() 'Test cases were ACC1002, FST4102
    Dim module_code As String, arr(), wsOutput As Worksheet, i As Long, objIE As Object
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True

    With wsOutput
        For i = 2 To 3                           '200
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then Exit For

            module_code = .Cells(i, 1)
            arr = GotoModules(module_code, objIE)
            wsOutput.Range("B" & i) = arr(0)
            wsOutput.Range("C" & i) = arr(1)
            wsOutput.Range("D" & i) = arr(2)
            wsOutput.Range("E" & i) = arr(3)
        Next i
    End With

    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function GotoModules(ByVal ModuleCode As String, ByVal objIE As Object) As Variant

    Dim module_title As String, module_description As String, module_prereq As String, module_preclusion As String

    If ModuleCode = vbNullString Then Exit Function

    objIE.Navigate ("https://myaces.nus.edu.sg/cors/jsp/report/ModuleDetailedInfo.jsp?acad_y=2017/2018&sem_c=2&mod_c=" & ModuleCode)

     While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim the_HTML_ToParse As String
    the_HTML_ToParse = objIE.document.Body.InnerHTML

    If InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Module Information") > 0 Then

        Dim HTML_Parse_Prereq As String, HTML_Parse_Preclusion As String, the_module_title As String, the_module_description As String, the_module_prereq As String, the_module_preclusion As String

        'Parses up to the point where "Module Information" string is
        the_HTML_ToParse = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Module Information"), Len(the_HTML_ToParse)) 'Parses from Module Information onwards
        HTML_Parse_Prereq = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Pre-requisite"), Len(the_HTML_ToParse))
        HTML_Parse_Preclusion = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "Preclusion"), Len(the_HTML_ToParse))

        'Module Title Parse
        the_HTML_ToParse = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "<TD colSpan=2>") + 14, Len(the_HTML_ToParse))
        the_module_title = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, 1, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "</TD></TR>") - 1)

        'Module Description Parse
        the_HTML_ToParse = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "<TD vAlign=top colSpan=2>") + 25, Len(the_HTML_ToParse))
        the_module_description = Mid(the_HTML_ToParse, 1, InStr(the_HTML_ToParse, "</TD></TR>") - 1)

        'Module Prerequisite Parse
        HTML_Parse_Prereq = Mid(HTML_Parse_Prereq, InStr(HTML_Parse_Prereq, "<TD colSpan=2>") + 14, Len(HTML_Parse_Prereq))
        the_module_prereq = Mid(HTML_Parse_Prereq, 1, InStr(HTML_Parse_Prereq, "</TD></TR>") - 1)

        'Module Preclusion Parse
        HTML_Parse_Preclusion = Mid(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, InStr(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, "<TD colSpan=2>") + 14, Len(HTML_Parse_Preclusion))
        the_module_preclusion = Mid(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, 1, InStr(HTML_Parse_Preclusion, "</TD></TR>") - 1)

    End If

    GotoModules = Array(the_module_title, the_module_description, the_module_prereq, the_module_preclusion)

End Function
```